# Ruby on rails 4: Unexpected result when filter datetime field in specified time zone with wice_grid

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone, wice-grid

The time zone is set to GMT +1100 through

```
config.time_zone = 'Australia/Sydney'
```

The date helper is set to calender by

```
Wice::Defaults::HELPER_STYLE = :calendar
```

When I filter a datetime field 'created_at'  by input the start date to '2014-10-21' and end date to '2014-10-21', the expected query should be

```
where created_at >= '2014-10-20 13:00:00' and created_at < '2014-10-21 13:00:00'
```

but actually  the generated sql is

```
where created_at >= '2014-10-21' and created_at < '2014-10-22'
```

After I look into the source code, I find the following code in line 112 in file 'lib/wice/columns/column_datetime.rb'

```
conditions << opts[:fr].to_date
```

If I remove the 'to_date', the query will be generated correctly.

What's the purpose of this 'to_date' conversion and how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Any comments ?  I have no idea on this for a long time.